# Is the Amazon tag useful?

Tags: discussion

Is it necessary that we have an [amazon](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/amazon) tag? Why not also have an Ebay tag? It seems to me that the Amazon tag is pointless, or am I not seeing its usefulness? Should we consider deleting the seldomly used Amazon tag? I also think that we should have a major tag cleanup. There are so many tags that need better wikis and some tags seem unbeneficial.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you search through the questions you can see that at one point Ubuntu integrated Amazon search in the dash. And there is an amazon webapp.

There are questions about connecting kindles(amazon product).

Using Amazon prime video.

And using an amazon ec2 with ubuntu installed.

So using the amazon tag has a lot more related to ubuntu, than only the shopping website.

Comment: But do those different Amazon-related topics relate to each other enough that it makes sense to group them all under an [tag:amazon] tag?

Comment: I suppose we could re-tag them to respective tags - we have a kindle tag allready, and amazon-ec2, so all is left is amazon-prime, and the webapp