# This [amazon] should die with honor!

Tags: discussion, burnination-request

> Yes, I found [this question](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/6946/1438484). But I think it is worth revisiting. Turns out [I wasn't supposed to ask multiple questions in one](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19771/burninate-request-amazon-microsoft-and-apple#comment43127_19771). Oops. This post is about the [amazon](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/amazon) tag, and ones for the [microsoft](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/microsoft) tag and the [apple](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/apple) will come later.

Meta SO doesn't like the [[amazon]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/amazon/info) tag, and requested it to be burninated. You can read their reasons [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/345643/16886597). I don't think we need the [amazon](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/amazon) tag on Ask Ubuntu.

*Can anyone be an expert in Amazon?*

I don't think so. One might be an expert in a specific Amazon product, say, AWS. But not all Amazon.

*Does it meaningfully add information to the context of the post?*

No. Other than saying that the question is in some way related to Amazon, it doesn't.

*Is it on topic for Ask Ubuntu?*

Depends on what specific Amazon thing they question is about.

Just looking at the [top questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/amazon?tab=Votes) for the [amazon](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/amazon) tag, we can see that they all are different. Some are about Alexa. Some about Amazon search in the dash. Others about Prime Video. Each question is about something different, and the [amazon](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/amazon) doesn't add meaning or clarify the topic at all.

Let's burninate the [amazon](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/amazon) tag.

Comment: What if someone wants to ask about, say, contributions to Ubuntu-packaged software by Amazon employees?

Comment: @Nemo I'm not sure I get what you mean. Can you give an example of a question like that?

Comment: @cocomac I think Nemo is saying about a potential problems arising as the Amazon employees package a open source package and someone might have a question about copyright or something like that?

Comment: Well, if it is about copyright, it probably belongs on Law SE, not here. I can't think of a situation where it would matter that the package publisher is an employee of Amazon. When I have a question, the issue, and some relevant details matter. Where the OP is employed is largely irrelevant.